# Multiplayer game programming, latency and starting players in sync with others

Tags: javascript, python, networking

I've been pecking away creating a multiplayer game where I used python for the server (with Twisted Framework) and javascript for the frontend (web game).

I'm a bit stumped at how I can start players in tine with others.  For example, the server sends the players a new map, which starts a countdown from 3, then they can race to the finish.

The issue is if someone has poor latency and another doesn't, the better connection would give them a head start, which is unfair.

I'm stumped as to how to at the very least limit this.  What measures can I take or look into?  I don't believe I can rely on ping time as that will fluctuate quite often.

Comment: you can simply sync with global clock. But if the two player need to interact, then you don't really have much chance for high latency.

Comment: @appleapple To be honest the issue has been solved since multiplayer exists by data prediction, state reconciliation and validation

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini if it's high latency, then the methods cannot help much. And not every game would fit.

Comment: @apple apple High latency is managed in every videogame with multiplayer feature. This is not unusual when latency increases for some reason to realize our bullet (speaking about first person shooters) even it it seems to hit the target, does not deliver damage to the target. This is because of reconciliation. The server, in this case, checked the position of the player and the bullet and has overrided the result of the prediction.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini does that a good result for a player? I don't think so. I don't even think it's used to solve **high** latency issue.

Comment: @appleapple "authoritative server, predictive client" is the only way multiplayer can be developed. If you know another pattern, please provide a paper about it, because the whole gamedev community rely on this. Valve guidelines: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini it's unsolved (and probably never can, or, it might someday no longer needed because of hardware improvement), and that why I said *you don't really have much chance for high latency* at first place.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when developing multiplayer features, the engine that run the game run **both** on *clients* and *server*.

When the server receive client data (along with their game clock) the state of the clients game *prediction* is *reconciled* with the server's one (the only source of truth).

[image]

You can find a very interesting introduction article about the topic [here](https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-server-game-architecture.html).

Notice also that some protocols, like [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), are by far more suitable than other for multiplayer realtime data exchange.